# Не могу держать постоянное подключение к серверу на Android

Tags: android, android-studio, сокет

Здравствуйте имею проблему написан сервер на java и необходим клиент на Android, проблема заключается в том, что приложение завершается после того как кто-нибудь подключиться, отправит сообщение или же отправится сообщение с приложения, ошибка [[image: Ошибка в потоке[1]]

К сожалению мне не хватает навыков и знаний чтобы исправить ошибку поэтому прошу помочь разобраться в чем я налажал

Код сервера

```
package ru.testing.chat.server;

import ru.testing.chat.network.TCPConnection;
import ru.testing.chat.network.TCPConnectionListener;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ChatServer implements TCPConnectionListener {
  public static void main(String[] args){
   new ChatServer();
}
private final ArrayList <TCPConnection> connections = new ArrayList<>();
private ChatServer(){
    System.out.println("Server running!");
    try {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8188);
        while (true){
            try {
                new TCPConnection(this, serverSocket.accept());
            } catch (IOException e){
                System.out.println("TCPConnection Exception "+e);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

@Override
public synchronized void onConnectionReady(TCPConnection tcpConnection) {
    connections.add(tcpConnection);
    sendAllConnect("Client Connected"+ tcpConnection);
}

@Override
public synchronized void onReceiveString(TCPConnection tcpConnection, String value) {
    sendAllConnect(value);
}

@Override
public synchronized void onDisconnect(TCPConnection tcpConnection) {
    connections.remove(tcpConnection);
    sendAllConnect("TCPConnection Disconnected");
}

@Override
public synchronized void onException(TCPConnection tcpConnection, Exception e) {
    System.out.println("TCPConnection "+e);
}

private void sendAllConnect(String msg){
    System.out.println(msg);
    final int cnt = connections.size();
    for(int i = 0; i<cnt; i++){
        connections.get(i).sendMessage(msg);
    }
}
```

}

Класс который делает TCP соединение

```
package ru.testing.chat.network;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

public class TCPConnection {
private final Socket socket;
private final Thread rxThread;
private final TCPConnectionListener eventListener;
private final BufferedReader in;
private final BufferedWriter out;

public TCPConnection(TCPConnectionListener eventListener, String ipAddress,int Port) throws IOException{
    this(eventListener,new Socket(ipAddress,Port));
}
public TCPConnection(TCPConnectionListener eventListener, Socket socket) throws IOException{
    this.eventListener = eventListener;
    this.socket = socket;
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( socket.getInputStream(), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    rxThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
                eventListener.onConnectionReady(TCPConnection.this);
                while(!rxThread.isInterrupted())
                {
                    String msg = in.readLine();
                    eventListener.onReceiveString(TCPConnection.this,msg);
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e){
                eventListener.onException(TCPConnection.this,e);
            }
            finally {
                eventListener.onDisconnect(TCPConnection.this);
            }
        }
    });
    rxThread.start();
}
public synchronized void sendMessage(String msg){
    try {
        out.write(msg + "\r\n");
        out.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        eventListener.onException(TCPConnection.this,e);
        Disconnect();
    }
}
public synchronized void Disconnect(){
    rxThread.interrupt();
    try {
        socket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        eventListener.onException(TCPConnection.this, e);
    }
}
@Override
public String toString(){
    return "TCPConnection :" + socket.getInetAddress() + " :"+socket.getPort();
}
```

}

Клиент на андройд

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TCPConnectionListener {
private TextView mLog;
private EditText mInput;
private EditText mNickname;
private Button mSend;
private TCPConnection tcpConnection;
private String IP_ADDRESS="192.168.1.40";
private int PORT=8188;
private CharSequence Logs="";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mLog=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Logs);
    mInput=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Input);
    mNickname=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.NickName);
    mSend=(Button)findViewById(R.id.SendMessage);

    Thread sThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ChatConnection();
        }
    });
    sThread.start();
    mSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            tcpConnection.sendMessage(mNickname.getText()+": "+mInput.getText());

        }
    });
}
public void ChatConnection(){
    InetAddress ipAdress=null;
    try {
         ipAdress=InetAddress.getByName(IP_ADDRESS);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    try{
        tcpConnection = new TCPConnection(this,ipAdress,PORT);
    }catch (IOException e){
        this.onException(tcpConnection,e);
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionReady(TCPConnection tcpConnection) {
    printMessage("Client is in Online");
}

@Override
public void onReceiveString(TCPConnection tcpConnection, String value) {
    printMessage(value);
}

@Override
public void onDisconnect(TCPConnection tcpConnection) {
    printMessage("Client is offline");
}

@Override
public void onException(TCPConnection tcpConnection, Exception e) {
    printMessage("TCPConnection error: "+e);
}
private synchronized  void printMessage(String mes){
    Thread mesThread= new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Logs=mLog.getText();
            mLog.setText(Logs+"\n"+mNickname.getText()+": "+mInput.getText());

        }
    });
    mesThread.start();
}
```

Ну и тот же TCPConnetion для android

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

public class TCPConnection {
private final Socket socket;
private final Thread rxThread;
private final TCPConnectionListener eventListener;
private final BufferedReader in;
private final BufferedWriter out;

public TCPConnection(TCPConnectionListener eventListener, InetAddress ipAddress,int Port) throws IOException{
    this(eventListener,new Socket(ipAddress,Port));
}
public TCPConnection(final TCPConnectionListener eventListener, Socket socket) throws IOException{
    this.eventListener = eventListener;
    this.socket = socket;
    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( socket.getInputStream(), Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream(),Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    rxThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
                eventListener.onConnectionReady(TCPConnection.this);
                while(!rxThread.isInterrupted())
                {
                    String msg = in.readLine();
                    eventListener.onReceiveString(TCPConnection.this,msg);
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e){
                eventListener.onException(TCPConnection.this,e);
            }
            finally {
                eventListener.onDisconnect(TCPConnection.this);
            }
        }
    });
    rxThread.start();
}
public synchronized void sendMessage(String msg){
    try {
        out.write(msg + "\r\n");
        out.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        eventListener.onException(TCPConnection.this,e);
        Disconnect();
    }
}
public synchronized void Disconnect(){
    rxThread.interrupt();
    try {
        socket.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        eventListener.onException(TCPConnection.this, e);
    }
}
@Override
public String toString(){
    return "TCPConnection :" + socket.getInetAddress() + " :"+socket.getPort();
}
```

}

Comment: `mLog.setText(Logs+"\n"+mNickname.getText()+": "+mInput.getText());` - для работы с view не в основном потоке используй, например, `Handler`

Comment: А в чем различие между Handler и обычным потоком, к сожалению читая сейчас разницы не вижу, можете ли вы пояснить

Comment: Нельзя из не-UI потока обращаться к UI элементам. В этом суть вашего креша и это пытается вам донести @AndreyMihalev

Comment: Понятно, сейчас попробую, ещё раз

Comment: Прошлый мой комментарий был не верен, и мне говорили верно ошибка была именно из-за того куска кода

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Итак методом проб и ошибок, я нашёл свой костыль, я начал вызывать отдельной процедурой соединение и отправку, и чтобы бесконечно не спамить подключения я создал "Конструктор" постоянного соединения, и ссылаясь на него отправляю сообщения на сервер. ниже видоизмененный кусок кода для клиента на андройд

```
mSend=(Button)findViewById(R.id.SendMessage);
mConnect=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Connect);
mSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Sending();
        }
    });
 mConnect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Connecting();
        }
    });

}
public void Sending(){
    Thread sThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            TtcpConnection.sendMessage(mNickname.getText()+": "+mInput.getText());


        }
    });
    sThread.start();
}

public void Connecting(){
    Thread sThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            TtcpConnection=ChatConnection();

        }
    });
    sThread.start();
}
public TCPConnection ChatConnection(){
    TCPConnection tcpConnection=null;
    InetAddress ipAdress=null;
    try {
         ipAdress=InetAddress.getByName(IP_ADDRESS);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    try{
        tcpConnection = new TCPConnection(this,ipAdress,PORT);
    }catch (IOException e){
        this.onException(tcpConnection,e);
    }
    return tcpConnection;
}
```

P.S. Когда смогу понять как использовать Handler, отправлю и другой кусок где всё записывается в TextView

UPD: Вот рабочий вариант клиента, хотя вероятнее всего сделан из гипсокартона)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TCPConnectionListener {
private TextView mLog;
private EditText mInput;
private EditText mNickname;
private Button mSend;
private Handler mHandler;
private Button mConnect;
public TCPConnection TtcpConnection;
private String IP_ADDRESS="192.168.1.40";
private int PORT=8188;
private String Logs="";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mLog=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Logs);
    mInput=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Input);
    mNickname=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.NickName);
    mSend=(Button)findViewById(R.id.SendMessage);
    mConnect=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Connect);
    mSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Sending();
        }
    });
    mConnect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Connecting();
        }
    });
    mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            Log.d("LOG-TAG","Всё Отлично");
            CharSequence text = mLog.getText()+Logs;
            if(msg.what==2) mLog.setText(text+"\n");
        }
    };


}
public void Sending(){
    Thread sThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            TtcpConnection.sendMessage(mNickname.getText()+": "+mInput.getText());


        }
    });
    sThread.start();
}

public void Connecting(){
    Thread sThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            TtcpConnection=ChatConnection();
            onConnectionReady(TtcpConnection);

        }
    });
    sThread.start();
}
public TCPConnection ChatConnection(){
    TCPConnection tcpConnection=null;
    InetAddress ipAdress=null;
    try {
         ipAdress=InetAddress.getByName(IP_ADDRESS);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    try{
        tcpConnection = new TCPConnection(this,ipAdress,PORT);
    }catch (IOException e){
        this.onException(tcpConnection,e);
    }
    return tcpConnection;
}

@Override
public void onConnectionReady(TCPConnection tcpConnection) {
    printMessage("Client is in Online");
}

@Override
public void onReceiveString(TCPConnection tcpConnection, String value) {
    printMessage(value);
}

@Override
public void onDisconnect(TCPConnection tcpConnection) {
    printMessage("Client is offline");
}

@Override
public void onException(TCPConnection tcpConnection, Exception e) {
    printMessage("TCPConnection error: "+e);
}
public synchronized void printMessage(String mes){
    Logs = mes;
    mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(2);

}
```

}